# An imitation of reading a C Struct from binary file in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.x, serialization

## Preliminary

I need to read a binary file constructed by writing a `Struct` to it with Python. So I decided to write a simple wrapper using `struct` module.

## Code

```
import struct


class structure:
    def __init__ ( self, little_endian = True ):
        self._little_endian = little_endian

        self._table  = dict() #stores field name, its format and value 
        self._pack  = list()  #stores field names in order fields must be read


    def add_field( self, field_name, field_format ):
        if field_name in self._table.keys():
            print "WARNING :: Field with name '%s' already exists in this structure" % field_name 
        elif field_format == "":
            print "WARNING :: Format cannot be an empty string"
        else:
            self._table[ field_name ] = { "format" : field_format, "value" : None }
            self._pack.append( field_name )
        #maybe error handling is required here


    def get_value( self, field_name ):
        try:
            return self._table[ field_name ][ "value" ]
        except KeyError:
            print "WARNING :: There is no such field named '%s' in this structure" % field_name 
            return None


    def get_format_string( self ):
        f_str = ""

        for key in self._pack:
            f_str += self._table[ key ][ "format" ]

        if (self._little_endian == True):
            f_str = "<" + f_str
        else:
            f_str = ">" + f_str

        return f_str


    def get_size( self ):
        return struct.calcsize( self.get_format_string() )


    def fill( self, file_ptr ):
        result = struct.Struct( self.get_format_string() ).unpack( file_ptr.read( self.get_size() ) )
        for (i,key) in enumerate(self._pack):
            self._table[ key ][ "value" ] = result[ i ]


    def show( self ):
        print "General info:"
        print "%20s = %s"  % ( "Format string", self.get_format_string() )
        print "%20s = %d" % ( "Size (bytes)", self.get_size() ) 
        print "Value:"
        for key in self._pack:
            print "%20s = " % key, self._table[ key ][ "value" ]
```

## Usage

Usage is straightforward. I used the real binary produced by OWON oscilloscope here so some of the values might look strange (consist non-printable characters).

```
import structure


s = structure.structure( little_endian=True )
s.add_field( "header", "10s" )
s.add_field( "serial", "14s" )
s.add_field( "string", "18s" )
s.add_field( "trig_time", "f" )
s.add_field( "float1", "f" )
s.add_field( "float2", "f" )

with open( "./data/trigger.bin" ) as f:
    s.fill( f )

s.show()
```

#### Output

```
General info:
       Format string = <10s14s18sfff
        Size (bytes) = 54
Value:
              header =  SPBS01e�
              serial =  SDS60621715234
              string =  
           trig_time =  99.0
              float1 =  3.41239206136e-06
              float2 =  0.001953125
```

---

As always any suggestions, ideas and critics are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

A major drawback of this design is that you **cannot reuse a single instance of `structure.structure` to read multiple records**.  Instead of `s.fill(file_ptr)`, consider making a method `s.read(f)` that returns an `OrderedDict` of the deserialized data.  (By the way, mentioning "pointer" in a parameter name isn't very Pythonic.)  Note that that would also replace your `.get_value()` method with a dictionary lookup, which can be dealt with more idiomatically. (Or, at least implement dict-compatible iteration and subscripting in your `structure` class.)

Switching to a reusable `.read()` method would also eliminate a point of awkwardness in your code, which is that `._table` is a **dict of dicts**, each having a `"format"` and a `"value"`.

In your implementation of `.fill()`, why not call **`.unpack_from(file_ptr)`** instead of `.unpack( file_ptr.read( self.get_size() ) )`?

A **more natural default endianness** would be either big-endian (because that is the standard Network Byte Order) or host byte order (because that is a non-opinionated choice that also happens to be the path of least resistance).

Whatever you design, it should accommodate the opposite operation — serializing data to a file.

Consider allowing a `structure` to contain nested `structure`s as fields.

The `.show()` method should probably be `.__str__()` instead.

I'm not convinced of the benefit of **requiring multiple calls to `.add_field()` to set up the `structure`**.  I'd prefer to have the constructor accept the field specification as a list of 2-tuples.  Not only would the calling code be cleaner, but the implementation of the `structure` class would be simpler as well if it is immutable.

I'm not a fan of your **printed warnings**.  Utility code, such as this, has absolutely no business contaminating `sys.stdout`, and ideally shouldn't print to `sys.stderr` either.  An end user would be completely clueless about what to do about these "warnings".  A programmer would also be puzzled about where these warnings came from (if it's a large program) and what actually happened as a consequence.  Rather, you should decide to either tolerate these situations gracefully or raise exceptions.  In my opinion…

- "Field with name … already exists" should raise an `ArgumentError`.
- "Format cannot be an empty string" should be tolerated (or perhaps an assertion failure).
- "There is no such field" would be eliminated altogether based on my suggestion to return an `OrderedDict`.  If you had to offer a `.get_value()` method, then you should just let the `KeyError` propagate.

Comment: Nice answer! I will go through it gradually. First question: Why do you say I cannot reuse a single instance for reading multiple records? More over, I DO it in my algorithm successfully (at least I don't see any inconsistencies). What is a problem I call `s.fill( f )` several times? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Well, you can `.fill()` the `structure` again, but then you would lose the data that was previously read.

Comment: Ah. Of course. In this sense you right.

Comment: Good catch on `unpack_from` method. I missed it.